# Is it safe to keep the default MOK.priv on after a fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04.2 with secure boot enabled?

Tags: ubuntu, uefi, secure-boot

I'm new to secure boot strategy. I found there is a default paris, `MOK.der` and `MOK.priv`, inside `shim` folder after a fresh installation of Ubuntu 18.04.2. If I understand correctly, they're there to make users easier to sign third-party kernel modules. However, it also confuses me as they seem bringing some security issues, which are against the purpose of secure boot. My questions are:

1. If I used this default pair to sign a kernel module, should I remove the pair (or at least the private key) after each signing and generate a new pair in that directory for the next signing?
2. For DKMS, does it look for that exact directory and file names to automatically sign kernel modules during building?
3. DKMS is supposed to rebuild and re-sign the modules during kernel upgrade. Does this re-signing process require the original key pairs?
4. Is it a general rule to avoid signing multiple modules with the same key?
5. Exclusive to 4), is it a good idea to set a passphrase to the private key so that it can be used to sign multiple modules, in a relatively safe way?